# Is it possible to launch passthru on XAMPP?

Tags: php, exe, launch, passthru

When I launch passthru -> exe on XAMPP, it doesn't give errors (PHP). Can I fork exe on XAMPP?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ob_start();
passthru("./Uc/UcCmd.exe 2.uni");
$var = ob_get_contents();
echo $var;

?>
```

But the file doesn't work
How can I check settings?

Comment: Unless you have further use for that output buffer, I suggest switching `ob_get_contents()` to `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: It's not clear whether it works. Paasthru

Comment: Try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php